# How to deny create tables without primary key in Firebird

Tags: sql, primary-key, firebird, database-trigger, firebird2.5

Is it possible to create (DDL) trigger in Firebird 2.5 which will deny create tables without primary key?

I read this article https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-psql-ddltriggers.html and google all over the internet, but didn't find any solution.

My code looks like:

```
create trigger trg_no_pk_table
before CREATE TABLE
as
begin

if (rdb$get_context('DDL_TRIGGER', '??????') ???????) then
        exception e_table_without_pk;
end
```

What do I need to wrote instead '????'?

Comment: I do not think so. I believe basically this is complex operation that consists of several smaller ones: among them is creating a bare table, and some latter step is "adding constraint of primary key type", so the table trigger would probably be fired up too early. Maybe using Trace API you can get into more details. You can also use ON DISCONNECT triggers to make warnings: create log table and when last client disconnects - enumerate all non-system tables and log those having no unique indexes

Comment: Also, you claim "in Firebird 2.5" then you link to the Firebird 3.0 relnotes. So, which is it ???

Comment: DDL triggers were introduced in Firebird 3.0, so you can't use them in Firebird 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

From Arioch'The comment:

> I believe basically this is complex operation that consists of
>   several smaller ones: among them is creating a bare table, and some
>   latter step is "adding constraint of primary key type", so the table
>   trigger would probably be fired up too early.

But If you still want to do this you can use:

```
if (rdb$get_context('DDL_TRIGGER', 'SQL_TEXT') not containing 'PRIMARY KEY') then
    exception e_table_without_pk;
```

**Note : this will work in Firebird 3 only**

Comment: That trigger can be easily foiled by including a comment with the text `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think the TS was talking about catching unexpected errors and omissions, not intentional malicious circumvention attempts. I would be more concerned about DB IDEs like IBExpert or Liquid Database, which would rehash operations however they like assuming end result is the same.